# triggering label to appear after firing 4 buttons onclick events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have an algorithm but don't know if this is the correct way. like mentioned, i would like my label to appear after the user clicks on 4 different buttons, each button with auto post back.

```
if(button 1 click && button 2 click && button 3 click && button 4 click)
label1.visible = true;
```

what should be the codes inside the if statement?

Comment: please don't add tags like "asp.net c#" to your title. That's what we have tags for.

Comment: A button does not have "Autopostback" property. You can use either OnClick or OnClientClick

Comment: i'm more concerned with why you'd want to do this anyway.  do other actions happen after the button clicks, or are they used solely for the purpose of showing the label?

Comment: @john thanks, i will note that

Comment: @user303523 thanks for the clarification, @nathangonzalez upon click button click, a string is stored and this string will combine with other strings and i only want label to show up after all 4 buttons are clicked. the label contains all the strings combined together

Answer (score 1):

you can use ViewState for this. on each button click event update the view state with the button flag. for example for button 1

```
if(ViewState["MyButtonState"]==null)
    ViewState["MyButtonState"]=1;
else
    ViewState["MyButtonState"]=((int)ViewState["MyButtonState"]) | 1;
```

you can use flag enumeration for this as well which is better approach. for button 1-4 use 1,2,4,8
and finally in the if statement

```
if(((int)ViewState["MyButtonState"])==0x0000000F)
    label1.Visible=true;
```

Comment: hello mubashir khan,
what is meant by " | 1;" in
ViewState["MyButtonState"]=((int)ViewState["MyButtonState"]) | 1;